# How do I extract my own smart phone usage data

Tags: ios

is there any way to extract MY OWN smartphone usage data? For example: the screen time or battery usage. I use iOS 14.4.
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to see just go to the settings app. But if you're talking about in code I have no idea

Comment: Yes, I know how to see it in settings. What I want to do is extract my usage data(the longer time, the better) out then do analysis and visualization...